# Usin case expression to wrap result in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have some type

```
data Result = Fail | Success deriving (Show)
```

expressing result of some operation and another arbitrary type

```
data MyData
```

and some function which processes the data

```
someAction :: MyData -> Result
someAction = if ... then Success else Fail
```

I need a wrapper function formatAction which calls someAction with MyData and formats the result of processing using case statement. Something like that:

```
formatAction :: MyData -> String
formatAction = let res = someAction in
  case res of 
    Success -> "OK"
    Fail -> "Fail"
```

It's not a valid code, but I can't undestand how to use result of the function with 'case' expression. Any idea?

Actually I meant a piece of code like that:

```
data Result = Fail | Success

data SomeData = SDS | SDF 

doSomeWork' :: SomeData -> Result
doSomeWork' SDS = Success
doSomeWork' _ = Fail

processData :: SomeData -> String
processData = let res = doSomeWork' in
    case res of 
        Success -> "OK"
        Fail -> "Fail"
```

It doesn't compile with the message:

**D:\Work\Haskell\revRange.hs:16:17:
    Couldn't match expected type `SomeData -> Result'
                with actual type`Result'
    In the pattern: Success
    In a case alternative: Success -> "OK"
    In the expression:
      case res of {
        Success -> "OK"
        Fail -> "Fail" }
D:\Work\Haskell\revRange.hs:16:28:
    Couldn't match expected type `SomeData -> String'
                with actual type`[Char]'
    In the expression: "OK"
    In a case alternative: Success -> "OK"
    In the expression:
      case res of {
        Success -> "OK"
        Fail -> "Fail" }
D:\Work\Haskell\revRange.hs:17:17:
    Couldn't match expected type `SomeData -> Result'
                with actual type`Result'
    In the pattern: Fail
    In a case alternative: Fail -> "Fail"
    In the expression:
      case res of {
        Success -> "OK"
        Fail -> "Fail" }
D:\Work\Haskell\revRange.hs:17:25:
    Couldn't match expected type `SomeData -> String'
                with actual type`[Char]'
    In the expression: "Fail"
    In a case alternative: Fail -> "Fail"
    In the expression:
      case res of {
        Success -> "OK"
        Fail -> "Fail" }**

Just can't catch how to match the result to the patterns.

Comment: If you are not going to use the derived `Show` instance, you can implement it yourself (`Success` mapped to `"OK"`, of source) and define `formatAction = show . someAction`.

Comment: OK. It's not about 'show'. This code doesn't compile because of:  Couldn't match expected type `MyData -> String'
                with actual type `[Char]'
    In the expression: "OK"
    In a case alternative: Success -> "OK"
    In the expression:
      case res of {
        Success -> "OK"
        Fail -> "Fail" }

Comment: The problem is that `processData` does not take any arguments, and does not forward them to `doSomeWork'`. Hence, `res` is a _function_, not a `SomeData` value, and you can't pattern match on that. Simon H. below did it correctly.

Comment: May be you are right. I've tried so many variants and probably decided to use pointless style only..:))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add the function parameter

```
formatAction :: MyData -> String
formatAction d = 
  case someAction d of 
    Success -> "OK"
    Fail -> "Fail"
```